# How to prove that if a function is symmetric about two mutually perpendicular line then it is also symmetric about their point of intersection

Tags: functions, symmetry

If $y = f(x)$ is symmetric about the lines $3x+4y+1=0$ and $4x-3y-7=0$ then prove that it must be symmetric about $(1,-1)$.

Can we comment on symmetricity of a function about point of intersection of two non perpendicular lines (given that the function is symmetric about those two line)?

Comment: Any thoughts of your own? What happens if you reflect a point across a line, and then across a perpendicular line? Where does it end up relative to its starting position?

Comment: On thinking graphically we can see that if a function is symmetric about two  mutually perpendicular lines it must be symmetric about the point of intersection, i was looking for some mathematical expression for this statement

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Gamma$ denote the graph of $f$: $\Gamma =\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 :y=f(x)\}$ (more generally, $\Gamma$ could be any set of points in the plane $\Bbb R^2$).

If $A, B$ are transformations of the plane (or arbitrary functions $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$), which both leave $\Gamma$ fixed, i.e. $A(\Gamma) :=\{A(p):p\in\Gamma\}\  =\Gamma=B(\Gamma)$, then so does the composite transformation $B\circ A$:
$$B\circ A\, (\Gamma) =\{B\circ A(p):p\in\Gamma\} =\{B(A(p)) :p\in\Gamma\}=B\big(\{A(p):p\in\Gamma\} \big) =B\big(A(\Gamma)\big)=B(\Gamma) =\Gamma$$

In this example, you can explicitly write up the coordinate mappings belonging to the two reflections, and then verify that their composition (in any order) is the reflection about the intersection point $p_1=(1, -1)$:
$$R_{p_1}=(x,y)\mapsto (2-x,\, -2-y)$$